# SilverStripe SortableGridField checkbox default

Tags: silverstripe

The SortableGridField module enables drag 'n drop on GridFields. It comes with a checkbox at the top of every GridField to enable drag 'n drop.

[image: SortableGridField]

Is it possible to set the checkbox to *checked* by default? As an extra functionality to that, is it also possible to hide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to the `SortableGridField` module is the `GridFieldOrderableRows` component in the [`SilverStripe Grid Field Extensions` module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions).

`GridFieldOrderableRows` adds a permanent handle on the left of each `GridField` row without needing to check a reorder check box.

To enable the `GridFieldOrderableRows` component on a `GridField` we do the following:

```
$config->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows('SortOrder'));
```

Comment: Fantastic module. Too bad there is no documentation on one of its extra features `GridFieldRequestHandler`